# Get page title in themeablebrowser Cordova/ Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Hi i'am working in Cordova v3.7 and [themeablebrowser Cordova plugin](https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser) 
in want to get title of the page in themeablebrowser i can't get it. I have tried  executeScript as specified in documentation but app crashes. here's what i have done so far.

```
function innAppInit(_url) {
    app.Log('browser news link=' + _url);
    if (_url == null) {
        _url = 'http://apache.org';
    }
    var ref = cordova.ThemeableBrowser.open(_url, '_blank', {

        backButtonCanClose: false,
        hideForwardButton: true,
        toolbarColor: '#239EC9',
        titleColor: '#FFFFFF',
        statusbarColor: '#239EC9',
        navButtonAlign: 'left',
        closeButtonAlign: 'right',
        menuButtonAlign: 'right',
        titleStaticText: 'Add New Web Page',

        menuButtonImage: 'themeablebrowser_stub_menu',
        menuButtonPressedImage: 'themeablebrowser_stub_menu_highlight',
        closeButtonImage: 'themeablebrowser_stub_close',
        closeButtonPressedImage: 'themeablebrowser_stub_close_highlight',
        backButtonImage: 'themeablebrowser_stub_back',
        backButtonPressedImage: 'themeablebrowser_stub_back_highlight',
        // menuTitle: 'Add Url to list',
        menuCancel: 'Cancel',
        menuItems: [{
            event: 'event_getURL',
            label: 'Add'
        }]
    }); 

    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
        try {
            app.Log('loadstart function');
            $('.ui-loader').show();

        } catch (e) {
            app.ErrorLog(e);
        }
    });
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
        try {
            app.Log('loadstop function');
            $('.ui-loader').hide();


             ref.executeScript({
                    code: 'return document.title'
                },
                function(values) {
                    alert(values);                       
                });

        } catch (e) {
            app.ErrorLog(e);
        }
    });
    ref.addEventListener('event_getURL', function(event) {
        try {

            var url = event.url;
            app.Log('get url=' + url);          
            ref.close();

        } catch (e) {
            app.ErrorLog(e);
        }
    });
    ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {
        try {
            app.Log('exit function');            

            $('.ui-loader').hide();

        } catch (e) {
            app.ErrorLog(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been raised and discussed on bug tracker.
https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser/issues/8

The gist is that the script you execute should be

```
document.title
```

Not

```
return document.title
```